# When transactionManager is not named "transactionManager" 

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, transactions

I am trying Spring 3(.0.2.RELEASE) and JPA2 and Hibernate 3.5.1-Final...
One thing upsets me is that spring seems only accept a transaction Manager named "transactionManager"

If I don't name it "transactionManager" , Spring will throws **NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager'** is defined.

Here is my config :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="destiny.data.mining"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="miningEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mining"/>
</bean>

<bean id="miningTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="miningEntityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdviceMining" transaction-manager="miningTransactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
    <tx:method name="get*"    read-only="true"/>
    <tx:method name="save*"   propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true"/>
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>  

<aop:config>
  <aop:pointcut id="methods" expression="execution(* destiny.utils.AbstractDao+.*(..))"/>
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdviceMining" pointcut-ref="methods"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="miningTransactionManager"/>
```

In this config , an Entity Manager Factory is **not** necessarily named "entityManagerFactory" , and "txAdvice" is **not** necessarily named "txAdvice" , either.
But I don't know why on earth Spring requires a transaction manager named "transactionManager" ?

**Is there any way not to name a transaction manager "transactionManager" ?**
(I'm running multiple spring config files , so I try my best to avoid name-conflicting)

test code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:mining.xml"})
public class MiningPersonDaoTest
{
  @Inject
  private EntityManagerFactory miningEntityManagerFactory;

  @Inject
  private MiningPersonDao miningPersonDao;


  @Transactional
  @Test
  public void testUpdate()
  {
    MiningPerson p = miningPersonDao.get(42L);
    p.setLocationName("OOXX");
    miningPersonDao.update(p);
    System.out.println(p);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that in the context of unit tests ([`TransactionalTestExecutionListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionalTestExecutionListener.html)), the code that otherwise looks up the transaction manager is **not** used ([`TransactionInterceptor#determineTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAspectSupport.html#determineTransactionManager(org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttribute))).

You could try to annotate your test class with [`@TransactionConfiguration`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/TransactionConfiguration.html), which accepts a `transactionManager` attribute. Not the most elegant way, but possibly the best option for the time being.

Comment: But I am still worried about if the DAO is injected into other framework (such as Wicket) , Is it still able to add @TransactionConfiguration to the wicket's compoment ?

Comment: You'll have to try it out to be sure, but I *think* that in the "real" context, you won't need any annotations - Spring will look up the correct transactionManager based on the bean id. Would be great if you could post your results here for the posterity to see as well.

Answer (score 3):

Today, I ran into same issue when I was trying very trivial example of Spring-Data JPA.  I had given custom name to transaction manager, "dmTransactionManager".  To fix it I had to specify it, I had to specify it like below:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.my.repository" transaction-manager-ref="dmTransactionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the following doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

> You can omit the transaction-manager attribute in the <tx:annotation-driven/> tag if the bean name of the TransactionManager that you want to wire in has the name transactionManager. If the TransactionManager bean that you want to dependency-inject has any other name, you have to use the transaction-manager attribute