# No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined - Rename transactionManager

Tags: java, junit4, activiti, spring-4

Im running a unit test under jUnit4 + spring4 and the thing is: my transactionManager is not called "transactionManager", it is called "transactionManagerActiviti". If I change the name everything is fine.

I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719646/no-bean-named-transactionmanager-is-defined) and [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027511/when-transactionmanager-is-not-named-transactionmanager) but I can't find the solution to this simple rename issue.

activiti.cfg.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManagerActiviti" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceActivitiLocal" />
</bean>

<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceActivitiLocal" />
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
   <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
   <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />

   <property name="customPostDeployers">
      <list>
         <bean class="org.activiti.engine.impl.rules.RulesDeployer" />
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

java class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/resources/activiti.cfg.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManagerActiviti")
public class CreditApplicantTest
{
   @Test
   public void deployProcess() 
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfiguration' defined in URL [file:src/test/resources/activiti.cfg.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180) [spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:641) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1157) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:280) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328) ~[spring-beans-4.0.7.RELEASE.jar:4.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Beans have an ID and a name have you tried setting the name attribute?

Comment: @AshleyFrieze I did, but got the same result

Comment: Can you post the part of your activiti.cfg.xml where you define your processEngineConfiguration bean?

Comment: @GergelyBacso activiti.cfg.xml updated and realized that transactionManager property is wrong! So I changed the ref to ref="transactionManagerActiviti" and now everything is ok. Would you like to answer so I can accept as the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so according to the logs your processEngineConfiguration bean has a propery called transactionManager. That is what you need to rename to get rid of this problem.